# Does calling a function with a lot of parameters consume more memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I looked for a pager where I can handle my site's thumbnails, but I did not find anything, so I had to write my own. I wrote a function which can make a pager for any data based on AJAX request:

```
function addPager(s, m, f, pager, current) {
if (!current) {current = 2;}
// m - element / page
// s - all elements
// f - ajax getter function's name like functionName(id, page)
// current - pressed button's index or p n f l as prev next first last
if (!pager) { // if the pager not appended
    if (s%m == 0) { p = s/m; } else {p = parseInt(s/m);} // get the pages number on all elements / elementsonpage
    $pager = $('<div class="pager clearfix"></div>') // pager holder box
    for (i=0;i<=p;i++) // append all pages to the pager holder and bind them for click
    {
        $('<span>'+(i+1)+'</span>')
        .bind("click", {page: i}, f)
        .click(function(){
            var ind = $(this).index();
            addPager(s, m, f, $(this).parent("div"), ind); // on click call this function again
        })
        .appendTo($pager); // the append
    }
    $pager.find("span").eq(0).addClass("on"); // find first element and add on class because its just appended
    $('<span class="mod">Next</span>').click(function(){ addPager(s, m, f, $(this).parent("div"), "n"); }).appendTo($pager); // prev, next, first, last buttons
    $('<span class="mod">Prev</span>').click(function(){ addPager(s, m, f, $(this).parent("div"), "p"); }).prependTo($pager);   
    $('<span class="mod">Last</span>').click(function(){ addPager(s, m, f, $(this).parent("div"), "l"); }).appendTo($pager);    
    $('<span class="mod">First</span>').click(function(){ addPager(s, m, f, $(this).parent("div"), "f"); }).prependTo($pager);  
    $pager.children("span").eq(0).addClass("on"); // add on class for the now 1st element (which is the first button)
    $pager.children("span").eq(1).addClass("disabled"); // disable the prev button
    $pager.children("span:not(.mod)").each(function(index) {
        if (((current-3) > (index+2)) || ((current+3) < (index+2))) { $(this).hide(); } else { $(this).show(); } // hide everything but the first 6 buttons (in case of 1000 pages i just show 1 .. 6)
        if (current == (index+2)) { $(this).addClass("on"); } // add on class to the first element - its probably useless because of the previous addonclass
      });
return($pager); // return it for the function which called. i append in the primary ajax function.

} 
else { // if the pager is already appended to the site
    if (s%m == 0) { p = s/m; } // calculate pages
    else {p = parseInt(s/m);} // calculate pages

    if (current == "n") {var i = $pager.find("span:not(.mod).on").index(); if ((i>=1) && (i<(p+2))) {addPager(s, m, f, pager, (i+1));}} // if current next goto next
    else if (current == "p") {var i = $pager.find("span:not(.mod).on").index(); if ((i>2) && (i<=(p+2))) {addPager(s, m, f, pager, (i-1));}} // if current prev goto prev
    else if (current == "f") { addPager(s, m, f, pager, 2); } // 1st
    else if (current == "l") { addPager(s, m, f, pager, (p+2)); } // last
    else { // if any other button pressed
        $pager = pager;
        $pager.find("span").removeClass("on disabled"); // remove on or disabled classes on each buttons
        $pager.find("span:not(.mod)").each(function(index) { // find numbered items only (without the spec buttons like prev or last)
            if (((current-3) > (index+2)) || ((current+3) < (index+2))) { $(this).hide(); } else { $(this).show(); } // hide all the buttons but the nearest ones
            if (current == (index+2)) { $(this).addClass("on"); }
        });
        if (current == 2) { $pager.children("span").eq(0).addClass("on");  $pager.children("span").eq(1).addClass("disabled"); }// first button makes the prev diabled and first active
        if (current == (p+2)) { $pager.children("span").eq(p+4).addClass("on"); $pager.children("span").eq(p+3).addClass("disabled"); } // last button makes the next diabled and last active
    }
}
}
```

... which can be used like this;

```
$.ajax {
...
addPager(allelementsnumber, elementsonpage, thisajaxfunctionsname); 
$pager.appendTo(whereyouwanttoappendthis);
...
}
```

CC Licensed, use it if you want, its working fine :)

1. When I call `addPager(param, param, param, param, param, param)` many times, with such a lot parameters... does it use lot of memory or something like that?
2. How can I make this function better or faster?

I made some comments for the simpler understanding however i think it's not a complicated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create an object with properties and then pass this instead of the multiple parameters. Each property of the object would represent one of the parameters. You could think of it like a options/configuration object.

You would then pass the object to the function as a single paratmeter, and then use the properties of the object.

This is a much better approach as it provides much better scalability in the long run.

However, I'm not sure there is an overhead with using many parameters. It's just difficult to read and not very scalable, in my opinion.